# Can a called Sub/Function end the execution of the caller Sub/Function?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Sub A` that at some point calls a `Sub B`:

```
Sub A()
    ...
    B
    ...
End Sub

Sub B()
    ...
End Sub
```

Is there any way I say to the Sub `B` (given some conditions) to terminate the execution entirely? 
If I would say something like `If True Then Exit Sub`, the `Sub B` would terminate but would passed the thread back to the `Sub A`. What I want, instead, is to figure out how (if possible) completely end the execution thread.

**BACKGROUND**

`Sub B` is supposed to be general method that raises an exception and then terminates the execution, to be used for all the too-complex cases where it's more worth the user provides the proper inputs instead of writing tons of lines of code to handle that kind of exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `End` to stop all VBA code running completely e.g.:

```
Sub B
    If disastrousCalamity Then End
Exit Sub
```

The only other ways I can think are two that I use:

1) You have a Public boolean e.g. `CancelBool` and set it to True when disaster strikes in B, then check this at your choke points in Sub A and exit A ... OR ...

2) Sub B is actually converted to a Function that returns a boolean so

```
Function B() As Boolean
If disaster then
    B = True
Else
    B = False
End If
End B
```

that way, when you call B from A you can use it like this: `If B = True Then Exit Sub` and A will cease also?!

Answer (score 0):

```
Global SubBReturnedError As Boolean

Sub A
    ' Some code
    Call B
    If SubBReturnedError = True Then End Sub
    ' Some code that may or may not get executed
End Sub

Sub B
    ' Some code
    ' Fudge happened
    If someError = True Then SubBReturnedError = True
    If SubBReturnedError = True Then End Sub
    ' Some code that won't get executed
End Sub
```

Personally I favor this solution over just `End`-ing it all, simply because it leaves you with more easily accessible options for when you almost inevitably go back to add to or refine the code.